# What's a less-artificial-sounding word for "up-to-date" and "up-to-date-ness"?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, technical

I'm describing a software design in a proposal document of mine, and I want to express my intention of the design being up-to-date, taking into consideration existing publications and available examples in its field. But I want to make this distinct from being *novel*, i.e. going even beyond what's been proposed or presented in other work. My best choice of term so far is "up to date". In Hebrew there's the construct עדכני which is also literally "up to date", but has an additional shade of meaning making it better suitable for my need; and there's a corresponding noun, עדכנות.

I would like a better word in English, especially in noun form but also for the adjective.

**Notes:**

- If you don't speak Hebrew, ignore what I said about the Hebrew word, a suggestion just having to do with English is fine.
- Being up-to-date is not binary, i.e. you can be partially up-to-date, or more, or less, up-to-date. I need that semantic aspect.

Comment: What is the additional shade of meaning which the Hebrew terms have?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: In Hebrew you have מעודכן and עדכני; the latter implies something more active, and is also more of a word in itself rather than a hyphenated construct - even though it's the result of combining עד with כאן ("up-to/until" and "here" respectively). It also weakly implies fashionability. And there's more to it I suppose. But never mind the Hebrew.

Comment: No, the Hebrew is important, because you have said that's the best choice so far, so in order to come up with an English equivalent it's of crucial importance to get everything possible about the nuances of the Hebrew. (Agreed, the word itself isn't important, but what it means and why it's a good fit for you **is**.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Ok, but few people know Hebrew; and I don't want to pre-filter suggestions; and suggestions with only English in mind will likely do even if they're not in the same vein as the Hebrew word I was thinking of.

Comment: But you still haven't said what the nuances are which you thought good!

Comment: What about "current" and "currency"?

Comment: @HotLicks: Much too inspecific. I mean, my design might be considered current merely by being proposed or adopted, well, currently. Not to mention the fact that I might say "Current designs are blah-blah-blah, but my design is special because yada-yada-yada". PS - Interesting nickname, that.

Comment: So you really want something like "cutting edge"?

Comment: How about *cutting edge* or *state of the art?* Frankly, I despise those clichés, but they seem to approximate the intended meaning. (Hyphenate when using either as an attributive adjective, of course.)

Comment: @HotLicks: If I could tone down the self-laudation of "cutting edge" some, that would be just right.

Comment: @BrianDonovan: Hmm... but state-of-the-art is binary. You can't be partially state-of-the-art. Actually, I should specify this requirement explicitly.

Comment: "Designed to become the new standard for...."? If you want to tone down the over-used "cutting edge," how about "leading edge," or is that too similar? "My design is special and will shape the future of...."?

Comment: [**contemporary**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contemporary) - Following modern ideas in style or design:

Answer (score 5):

What about **current**, **contemporary**, or even just **modern**? There are also more marketing-like terms which you could consider: "best-practice", "best-of-breed", etc.

> The design is current, employing contemporary design techniques and a modern approach.

Nouns may sound awkward in certain cases, so I'd avoid their use. They'll likely be used in the passive voice too, which isn't great either. Here are some suggestions, nonetheless:

- the **currency** of the design [awkward due to the double meaning]
- the **modernity** of the design
- the **ubiquity** of the design
- the **pervasiveness** of the design

Comment: What about the noun form of these?

Comment: I have edited it to add some noun ideas

Comment: ubiquitous and pervasie are not relevant here. As for "modern", modern things are not necessarily up-to-date, I don't believe that's implied in the word. "current" have more of the right implication, but this would be confused with "transpiring right now", at least in some contexts; and if I write about "the currency of X" it sounds like I'm talking about money. ... I don't now...

Comment: I agree that ubiquitous and pervisive are not entirely the same as up-to-date-ness. I've had this exact problem before, and I couldn't find a better word than currency. In the end I ditched it for the same reason as you -- the other meaning, but I still think it's the best option. Failing that, reword it so you don't need a noun.

Comment: @einpoklum I agree that Brad’s good notion of “current” sounds close (+1) and if you’d consider a phrase, you could easily get to “[up to/meets/exceeds current industry standards](https://books.google.com/books?id=ITEJAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA394&dq=%22up+to+current+industry+standards%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8lbSC58jLAhVIXB4KHXjpDyEQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22up%20to%20current%20industry%20standards%22&f=false)” from his answer.

Answer (score -1):

It might not perfectly capture what you mean, but what about **sophisticated** (*noun: sophistication*)?

Comment: Can you explain why you think that would be a good choice?